# The power LED will not light- power supply is fine

Tags: power, led, boot-issues

The power (red) LED on my pi will not light. It was working fine, but then suddenly, while I was using it, poof! At first it blinked occasionally, now it just won't turn on. The power supply was as it was when everything was functional.
BTW I was using the pi to test some code where the GPIO pins were connected to a h bridge, which was connected to some DC motors and a 9v battery.

Comment: How do you know the power supply is fine?  Do any components on the Pi now get very hot?  Does the Pi boot?  Can you **carefully** measure the voltage between the ground and 5V pins on the expansion header? Ditto between ground and the 3V3 pins?  What model Pi do you have?

Comment: I am using the model b+, the central component gets very hot and the pi will not boot. I am not sure I have the equipment to measure the voltage.

Comment: I am afraid that sounds terminal, it seems like the main chip has blown.

Comment: So do you think I should buy another one? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think you will have to buy another.  It sounds like the SoC has blown.  I know of no way of replacing that for less than the cost of a new Pi.  Even if you did replace the SoC (unlikely as you can't buy them) other components will probably have blown as well.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I am really surprised how helpful people on this site are. :) However, would you know what might have caused this, or what I should do to prevent this in the future. I was trying to control 4 DC motors through a DC motor through a H bridge and was supplying an additional 9  volts from a 9v battery. I did successfully get a motor to run, and that it is when everything stopped working.

Comment: I'd have to assume that a wrong voltage got fed to the Pi (say 9V to the 5V or 3.3V rail, or more than 3.3V to a gpio).  You'd have to post a photo of your connections to have any chance of finding out what went wrong.

Comment: How would I upload it? In summary, I have a 9 volt battery connected to the 12v and the ground on the H bridge. The 5v and ground from the pi is connected to the 5v and ground on the H bridge. All of the pins on the H bridge (the enables and inputs) are all connected to seperate GPIO pins. Output A on the H bridge is connected to two motors. The same is true for output B. The 4 motors I am using are the 'Flat 3V DC Miniature Model Electric Motor 2mm Shaft 1.5-4.5V Arduino UK A401'. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: You can insert images when you edit.  It'll give you the option to download from your computer.  Your description sounds fine.  How many enable pins did you connect?

Comment: I connected all of the enable pins to separate GPIO pins.

Comment: How many enable pins were there?

Comment: Both enable A and B are connected to separate GPIO pins.

Comment: Is this because the RPi B+ is unsuitable for this job?

Comment: Not at all.  I am just trying to establish what could have gone wrong.  So you connected a total of two gpios to the enable pins?

Comment: A total of four.

Comment: Any ideas on what I did wrong??

Comment: There are two enable pins. If you connected four gpios then two would have been connected to the enable pins, the other two gpios were presumably connected to jumpers behind the enable pins.  The jumpers carry 5V.  They could easily have killed the gpio/Pi.

Comment: There are two pins for each enable. 4 GPIO pins were used just for the enables. Then the inputs were connected as well. BTW what were the 5v jumpers connected to, what should have they been connected to?

Comment: There is ONE pin for ENA and ONE pin for ENB.  Behind those pins are jumpers which should NOT be connected to a Pi gpio.

Comment: Oh so was that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you overload the pi or there is insufficient power. This could be solved by increasing the input current >2 amp and powering up other peripherals using an external power.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments you might have a motor driver board similar to this one.

[image: L298N based motor driver board]

You should only connect Pi gpios to the pins labelled ENA, IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4, and ENB.

Behind ENA/ENB are jumper pins marked in red.

These pins carry 5V and should NEVER be connected to a Pi gpio.

They are a convenience.  If you do not want to have ENA/ENB under software control you can enable ENA/ENB by connecting a jumper between the jumper and enable pin (as shown in the image).

Comment: Oh... thanks. So was that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the red LED does not light then either the power supply itself is bad (which you say is not the case)

or

perhaps the internal voltage regulator is bad.

---

The first step I would take is a reading at the 5V pin.  Make sure the power is actually making it through.

Then I would test the 3.3V pin.

---

Botttom line:  The Red LED should light if there is sufficient 5V power.